# Folder alias in ExtendScript is broken (Illustrator)

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

```
//there's existing untitled folder 
//and untitled folder's alias on desktop

var folderName="untitled folder"
var folderAliasName="untitled folder alias"
var folderAlias=new Folder(Folder.desktop+"/"+folderAliasName)

//calling resolve on alias returns file instead of folder?!
var resolvedFolder=Folder(folderAlias.resolve())

//seems it just points to (non existing) file
alert(resolvedFolder.constructor)//File (?!)
```

am I doing something wrong? any hack around this? anyone, please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot `name` after `constructor`:

```
alert(resolvedFolder.constructor.name) // it returns 'Folder'
resolvedFolder.execute(); // it opens the folder, just to be sure
```

I tried it on Windows and MacOS it works fine.

By the way `folderAlias` is a file rather than a folder. Since it just an alias. It's not an error, though. Extendscript handles it well.

Comment: No its not the case. resolvedFolder.constructor.name  gets me File. which version of AI/macOs you are using? what do you get when you call getFiles() on resolvedFolder?

Comment: `getFiles()` works fine for me. I tried it on Windows CS6, MacOS CS5 and MacOS CC 2018 (22.1). Perhaps there is something wrong with your alias.

Comment: Or there is something wrong with MacOS. Because I'm still is on High Sierra. Lucky me :)

Comment: Coincidently, I am on High Sierra too.  ..I've just tested on Ai CS6 -  works happily. Apparently, this is Ai issue for CC2020 on Mac (version 24.0.1). Thanks for all the testing and input!